# Lightswitch html dropdown list limits matches to 15?

Tags: javascript, dropdown, visual-studio-lightswitch

In my Lightswitch application the main lookup is based on serial number which then offers model/ serial combos that match on the serial number. Unfortunately there are now serial numbers that match more than 15 models and only the first 15 appear to be shown.

My question is there any way to show all the matches in the dropdown instead of limiting them?

Thanks for the assistance.
Radster

Answer (score 1):

For those still using Lightswitch I have found the solution. The 15 limit is buried in the msls-2.5.2.js file in the scripts directory underneath HTMLClient. Just search for itemlimit and you will eventually get to see the 15 change it to whatever and minify the file and you are good to go.